# Prompt_command to reload from .bash_history

Tags: bash, environment-variables, history

My `.bashrc` contains the following:

```
HISTSIZE=30000
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"
export HISTSIZE PROMPT_COMMAND
```

What I notice:

- the `.bash_history` *does* get appended.
- history on a given terminal session does *not* include entries appended from other terminal sessions

The desired behavior is to have the `.bash_history` reloaded after any command on any terminal. What is the way to achieve this?  Presumably it would be a modification to the `PROMPT_COMMAND` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `history -a` command only appends to the history file. This doesn't affect any shell session unless you also read from it. So, what you're looking for is:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r"
```

As explained in `help history`:

```
  -r    read the history file and append the contents to the history
        list
```

This way, you will first append your current shell's history to `$HISTFILE` and then read from it, importing the history appended from any other shell instance into the current one.

Note that if you run a command in one terminal, it won't appear in the history of another until you run a command in the second. The `$PROMPT_COMMAND` is run before a prompt is shown, so if the second terminal is just open and sitting there, it won't read the new command run in the first one until you run something in the second and a new prompt is shown.

Comment: I've added `history -r` now - and that does fix the issue:  thanks.  Afa "running something new" - the "new" something is `history | tail -n 100` so that was being done properly.